# Moving elements between Tkinter Treeview widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to implement a function that lets me drag and drop treeview entries between N treeview widgets. I played around with detach/insert as well as move. While I got drag and drop reordering within widgets running, I cannot figure out how to drop them into another.